# PostgreSQL relation not found, returns lowercase

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to insert some values into a table in a PostgreSQL database.
Should be simple enough to do but i always get an error when trying to run the command

if i try

```
INSERT INTO "Map" VALUES ('Map_hvi_to_platform', 'ULX_hvi', 276, 'ULX_platforms', 278, 'A', 'ccdadm', now(), '', 280);
```

I get the error: `ERROR:  relation "map_hvi_to_platform" does not exist`
Notice it returns 'map' instead of 'Map'

If i try

```
INSERT INTO "Map" VALUES ("Map_hvi_to_platform", 'ULX_hvi', 276, 'ULX_platforms', 278, 'A', 'ccdadm', now(), '', 280);
```

I get the error: `ERROR:  column "Map_hvi_to_platform" does not exist`

But if i run `SELECT * FROM "Map_hvi_to_platform";`
It does return all the values stored in that table

Here is the CREATE TABLE (i did not write this, i'm working on an already built database)

```
-- Table: "Map"

-- DROP TABLE "Map";

CREATE TABLE "Map"
(
  "IdDomain" regclass NOT NULL, -- MODE: reserved
  "IdClass1" regclass NOT NULL, -- MODE: reserved
  "IdObj1" integer NOT NULL, -- MODE: reserved
  "IdClass2" regclass NOT NULL, -- MODE: reserved
  "IdObj2" integer NOT NULL, -- MODE: reserved
  "Status" character(1), -- MODE: reserved
  "User" character varying(100), -- MODE: reserved
  "BeginDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), -- MODE: reserved
  "EndDate" timestamp without time zone, -- MODE: reserved
  "Id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT _cm_new_card_id(), -- MODE: reserved
  CONSTRAINT "Map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("IdDomain", "IdClass1", "IdObj1", "IdClass2", "IdObj2")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Is there any way to overcome this? I'm kinda new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you put the column types, the Create table script or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using quoted identifiers will give you **much** more trouble in the long run than they are actually worth (which is debatable in the first place).

In your case you are trying to insert a `regclass` value. The value `"Map_hvi_to_platform"` doesn't work because the `insert` statement treats it as a column identifier.

The string literal `'Map_hvi_to_platform'` *could* automatically be cast to a regclass but in that case the usual rules for (the dreaded) quoted identifiers apply and Postgres looks for a table name `map_hvi_to_platform`.

You actually need to combine both quoting styles together:

```
INSERT INTO "Map" 
  VALUES 
('"Map_hvi_to_platform"', '"ULX_hvi"', 276, '"ULX_platforms"', 278, 'A', 'ccdadm', now(), '', 280);
```

But once you get the regclass values right, you will get the next error, because `''` is not a valid constant for a timestamp value. You need to use `null` if you don't want to supply a value for that.

In general it is considered bad coding style to not list the column names in the `insert` statement. Explicitly listing them has two advantages: it's easier for other people to understand which value goes into which column and it's more robust against changes to the table structure.

So the final statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO "Map" 
  ("IdDomain", "IdClass1", "IdObj1", "IdClass2", "IdObj2", "Status", "User", "BeginDate", "EndDate", "Id")
VALUES 
  ('"Map_hvi_to_platform"', '"ULX_hvi"', 276, '"ULX_platforms"', 278, 'A', 'ccdadm', now(), null, 280);
```

(Note the `null` value for `"EndDate"`)

---

<sup>I have to admit I can't possible imagine a situation where it makes sense to store table names in another table. This does smell a bit like a broken design</sup>

Comment: Storing table/column names is needed when an extention needs its own catalogs, such as in GIS systems.

Comment: @joop: I would be _very_ surprised if those tables belonged to a Postgres extension or if Alex is working on one.

Comment: I did not mean extention as postgres extention, but in the general sense.

Comment: @joop: so you are referring to the anti-pattern "Entity-Attribute-Value". There are usually better ways of doing that - especially with Postgres.

Comment: Nono. BTW: even EAV-avoiding methods , involving dynamic SQL , need a way to store the affected tablenames / column names somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem because the column type is regclass which allows postgres to check that you are inserting the name of an existing table name (I'm simplyfing on this). The problem is that your table (Map_hvi_to_platform) been created using "" so you must reference it using the double quotes i.e.

```
Select * from "Map_hvi_to_platform"
```

in order to make your insert work you must issue something like

```
INSERT INTO "Map" VALUES ('"Map_hvi_to_platform"', 'ULX_hvi', 276, 'ULX_platforms', 278, 'A', 'ccdadm', now(), '', 280);
```

i.e. you must include the double quotes in the name between the single quotes; the name you must use is "Map_hvi_to_platform" and not Map_hvi_to_platform

I did a simple test case and it worked.